# Opera: button text shifts on click

Tags: css, button, opera

Unlike other browsers Opera causes `<button>` inner text shifting for 1 pixel right and 1 pixel down when clicked. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: have you tried any reset.css tricks? http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.3/build/cssreset/cssreset.css

Comment: I temporarily solved this problem using css hack: 
`button {
 padding: 9px 20px;
}
noindex:-o-prefocus, button:active {
 padding: 8px 21px 10px 19px;
}`

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour (Opera 12.11, Opera Next 12.11). Can you provide an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mcrss/8a972/

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Opera 15

Answer (score 0):

You can use css padding & height, width with percentage

use this

```
.stylename
          {
          height:10%;
          width:230%;
          padding-top:3px;
          padding-bottom:3px;
          padding-left:5px;
          padding-right:5px;
          font-size:10pt;
          /*You can Change height / Width and Padding according to you*/
          }
```